# Using WinForms font names in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, fonts

have an old app that we are porting to WPF. One feature of the old app was RichText-style text boxes where users can chose fontfamily and font size for certain text. This is then serialized and saved in a SQL server.

The issue I have run into is that font names in WinForms and WPF do not match!

For example; I have a font installed on my machine called "Gotham-Bold". It's displayed in the Windows\Fonts folder by that name, and I can use that font in Word documents and in WinForm applications using that name.

But in WPF that same font is shown with the name "Gotham".

*So, how do I set the FontFamily in WPF using the same name we use in WinForms?*

Example in WinForms:

```
this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Gotham-Bold", 20F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 76);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(92, 31);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "label1";
```

Example in WPF:

```
<Label Content="Example" FontFamily="Gotham" FontSize="20"/>
```

These are equivalent and uses the same ttf-file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change font family programmatically in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609956/change-font-family-programmatically-in-wpf)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ No, it does not.

Comment: Can you explain then what doesn't work?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ When setting the FontFamily property in WPF, either in XAML or in code-behind, you can not always use the same font-name as you would in a WinForms application.

Comment: In `wpf`, `FontWeight` is the `WinForm` equivalent of `FontStyle`, they will not match...

Comment: Is this of help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903445/wpf-multiple-font-files-of-the-same-family

Comment: @PaulF It helped me narrow down the issue. WinForms uses the exact name from the ttf metadata, while WPF seems assumes the font family is the part before the dash if the part after the dash is "Bold". Using FontForge to rename the font from Gotham-Bold to Gotham-Bald changes WPFs behaviour. I do have other fonts which have similar issues but doesn't have the same naming convention so I'm not sure I'm any closer to a sollution yet. But it gives me something to investigate.